# Data mining for US demographics

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, us-census

Where can I get US population demographics data for various MSA (MSA level data)? An early response is appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics.

Answer (score 3):

You can find demographic data on Metropolitan Statistical Areas through [American FactFinder](http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/12_1YR/DP02/0100000US.31000). Depending on how accurate, timely, or complete you want your data to be, you can decide between 1-Year averaged estimates, 3-Year averaged estimates, or 5-Year averaged estimates. The 1-Year averaged estimates cover areas with populations over 65,000 (with an average sampling rate of 1.5% of the population); The 3-Year averaged estimates covers areas with populations over 20,000 (with an average sampling rate of 4.5% of the population; and the 5-Year averaged estimates will have the largest sample with an average sampling rate of 7.5% of the population.